# How to create the different types of Videos by using the Images

Tags: ios, objective-c

I already created Video by using images But I need to create the video with different transition effects when its changing from one image to another.Thanks for the advance help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use photoshop to crate gif animated videos through images.

Here is a procedure.

**Step 1:** 
 click on File > Scripts > Load Files Into Stack.

Then, click Browse and choose the image files that you would like to use in your GIF, then click OK.

**Step 2:** Open The Timeline Window
go to the top navigation, then click Window > Timeline.

Now click “Create Frame Animation, in the Timeline window.
It won’t happen automatically, for this, choose it from the dropdown menu  but make sure to actually click it or the frame animation options will not show up.

**Step 3:** For every frame, create a new layer.
For doing this, select all the layers by from top navigation menu and then choose Select > All Layers.

**Step-4**
Now, click the menu icon present on the right side of the Timeline screen.

Now use the dropdown menu to choose “Create new layer for each new frame”

**Step 5:** choose “Make Frames From Layers.” by Opening the same menu icon on the right
This will generate each layer as a frame of your GIF

**Step 6:** Now set the time you want the frame to switch from one to other.
This can be done by clicking the time options below each frame and choosing how long you want it it to appear. 
choose-frame-time

**Step 7:** Now, at the bottom of the toolbar, set the number of loops
 You can set manually by clicking on “custom”

**Step 8:** You GIF is ready.
Now you can simply click on the play button to preview the new GIF that you have created.

Hope It Helps

Oodles Studio

Comment: If you know how to implement in objective c...Please share the reply